# Find row in datatable with specific id

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I have two columns in a datatable:

```
ID, Calls.
```

How do I find what the value of Calls is `where ID = 5`?

5 could be anynumber, its just for example. Each row has a unique ID.

Comment: Couldn't you do this as part of the select statement? 
"SELECT ID, Calls FROM MyTable WHERE ID=@id_search". Then just provide the "@id_search" parameter to the database call. This is going to be faster than LINQ, especially assuming ID is a primary key or indexed.

Comment: Not a database, dataset/datatable im afraid.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Make a string criteria to search for, like this:

```
string searchExpression = "ID = 5"
```

Then use the `.Select()` method of the `DataTable` object, like this:

```
DataRow[] foundRows = YourDataTable.Select(searchExpression);
```

Now you can loop through the results, like this:

```
int numberOfCalls;
bool result;
foreach(DataRow dr in foundRows)
{
    // Get value of Calls here
    result = Int32.TryParse(dr["Calls"], out numberOfCalls);

    // Optionally, you can check the result of the attempted try parse here
    // and do something if you wish
    if(result)
    {
        // Try parse to 32-bit integer worked

    }
    else
    {
        // Try parse to 32-bit integer failed

    }
}
```

Comment: This does give me the datarow, but how do i get the specific value from the column calls

Comment: @RyanMurphy - updated answer to show how to get value out of row and safely attempt to parse the value.

Comment: What if I wanted to get the row number for the result. how can I get that?

Answer (score 56):

You can use LINQ to DataSet/DataTable

```
var rows = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .Where(r=> r.Field<int>("ID") == 5);
```

Since each row has a unique ID, you should use `Single/SingleOrDefault` which would throw exception if you get multiple records back.

```
DataRow dr = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .SingleOrDefault(r=> r.Field<int>("ID") == 5);
```

*(Substitute `int` for the type of your ID field)*

Comment: Some time unable select rows from table using this "DataRow[] foundRows = YourDataTable.Select(searchExpression);". But when I am using LINQ. Its working good. Thanks Habib.

Answer (score 14):

I could use the following code. 
Thanks everyone.

```
int intID = 5;
DataTable Dt = MyFuctions.GetData();
Dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { Dt.Columns["ID"] };
DataRow Drw = Dt.Rows.Find(intID);
if (Drw != null) Dt.Rows.Remove(Drw);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that a datatable can have a primary key!  Wasn't aware that existed, and that made a huge performance difference in my case.

Answer (score 11):

You can try with method select

```
DataRow[] rows = table.Select("ID = 7");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
DataRow dataRow = dataTable.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(r => Convert.ToInt32(r["ID"]) == 5);
if (dataRow != null)
{
    // code
}
```

If it is a typed DataSet:

```
MyDatasetType.MyDataTableRow dataRow = dataSet.MyDataTable.FirstOrDefault(r => r.ID == 5);
if (dataRow != null)
{
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
DataRow foundRow = FinalDt.Rows.Find(Value);
```

but set at lease one primary key

Comment: performance should be an O(log n) operation per Ms docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection.find?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 2):

Hello just create a simple function that looks as shown below.. That returns all rows where the call parameter entered is valid or true.

```
 public  DataTable SearchRecords(string Col1, DataTable RecordDT_, int KeyWORD)
    {
        TempTable = RecordDT_;
        DataView DV = new DataView(TempTable);
        DV.RowFilter = string.Format(string.Format("Convert({0},'System.String')",Col1) + " LIKE '{0}'", KeyWORD);
        return DV.ToTable();
    }
```

and simply call it as shown below;

```
  DataTable RowsFound=SearchRecords("IdColumn", OriginalTable,5);
```

where 5 is the ID.
Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Try avoiding unnecessary loops and go for this if needed.

```
string SearchByColumn = "ColumnName=" + value;
DataRow[] hasRows = currentDataTable.Select(SearchByColumn);
if (hasRows.Length == 0)
{
    //your logic goes here
}
else
{
    //your logic goes here
}
```

If you want to search by specific ID then there should be a primary key in a table.